# Signifo de "ne pardoninda"

Tags: meaning

Bonan!

Iu eniris malĝustan grupon de Telegram kaj komencis babili pri io ekstertema. Partoprenanto tuj klarigis ke la grupo temas pri io alia kaj la ĵus alveninto pardonpetis:

```
Pardonu!
```

kaj oni respondis jene:

```
Ne pardoninda!
```

Ĉu tio signifas ke la afero estas tiel grava, ke oni ĝin ne povas pardoni, aŭ tiel malgrava ke ne indas pardonpeti?

Aldono: mi ŝatus scii ĉu *ne pardoninda!* estas plursignifa, laŭ la lingvaj reguloj. En la supra ekzemplo oni ja komprenas kion oni *volis* komuniki, sed, ĉu tiu estas la *fakta* signifo?

Comment: "kiun signifon vi _sentis_?" almost by definition asks for primarily opinion-based answers. Note that [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange is meant for questions that at least theoretically can have answers that are objectively right or wrong. It's not a tool to conduct surveys and polls. Please [edit] your question if you think you can and want to make it not primarily opinion-based.

Comment: nepardonebla <-> tute ne (spaco) pardoninda

Comment: @das-g mi redaktis la demandon por sekvi la regulojn.

Comment: Dankon pro la modifo al la demando. Mi remalfermis ĝin.

Answer (score 3):

Mi suspektas, ke per la esprimo *ne pardoninda!* oni iel celas imiti la esprimon *ne dankinde!*, kiu laŭ PIV estas "ĝentila formulo, por ŝparigi al iu la dankojn". Tiuokaze, ĝi estu *ne pardonind**e**!* Tamen, ŝajnas ke por la verbo *pardoni* tia ĝentila formulo ne aperas en la vortaro nek en la lingvouzo. Sekve, la manko de kunteksto ne garantios la celatan sencon kaj la esprimo *ne pardoninde!* povus esti interpretata kiel io nepardonebla. En Tekstaro ĝi aperas nur dufoje kaj unuvorte (*nepardoninde*), ambaŭ en la senco de *nepardonebla*. Kontraste, *ne dankinde* / *nedankinde* aperas sesfoje, ĉiuj en la senco de *ne estas necese danki*.

Jen aliaj ebloj malpli kunteksto-dependaj:

*(estas) nenecese pardonpeti! | (estas) nenio pardoninda!*

Answer (score 1):

Plej verŝajne

> Ne pardoninda!

signifas, ke ne estas necesa pardonpeti. Aliokaze mi sensus la reagon absurda.

Neniu kredus, "Ne dankinde!" signifus, ke oni ne povas danki por afero ĉar estas tiom grandega.

Se ne eblas pardoni ion, mi dirus:

> Ne pardonebla!

Comment: Mi komprenas vian _plej verŝajne_ sed, se ne estus kunteksto kaj vi nur aŭdus _ne pardoninda!_ tra fenestro, ĉu la signifo estus sama? Mi ŝatus scii ĉu tio estas plursenca laŭ la kunteksto. (tuŝeto nevola per kubuto ĉetable / varma kafo sur nova ĉemizo). _nedankinda_ estas _ne meritanta dankon_, do _nepardoninda_ devus esti _ne meritanta pardonon_, ĉu?

Comment: I think it's just a mistake. *Pardoni* has nothing to do with *indeco*.